# Spring Boot - how to include REST endpoint from dependency?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring / Spring Boot, so please pardon if what I am asking is trivial.

I have created Spring Boot application which exposes the REST endpoint:

```
package com.atomic.contentguard;

...
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class AcgController {

@RequestMapping(value="/acg-status",method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
 public String getStatus(){     
    return "Hi there!";
 }
}
```

It all works fine when you run it as standalone Spring Boot application, the endpoint is testable by going to http://localhost:8080/rest/acg-status.

**What I want to achieve is to "bring it" into another application, which would be including my application as a dependency in the pom.xml, expecting this REST endpoint to show up in it.**

What I've done so far is included it in another project pom.xml as:

```
</dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atomic</groupId>
        <artifactId>contentguard</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And then included it in that other application @ComponentScan section of config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.atomic.contentguard"})
public class EnvInfoWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

It does not however show up when you run target application:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/other-application-context/rest/acg-status] in DispatcherServlet with name 'envinfo-dispatcher'
```

What am I missing / doing wrong?

Comment: what is the  url that you try to invoke and can you update the error trace

Comment: @kuhajeyan I open browser and go to: http://localhost:8080/[other-application-context]/rest/acg-status

Comment: Try using `localhost:8080/rest/acg-status`.

Comment: @OleksiyDeverishchev  were you able to access other controller defined [other application context] ?

Comment: @kuhajeyan yes - that app works fine, but my endpoint which I am bring in via maven import does not show up.

Comment: @RITZXAVI it should not work like that. If other application is loading by going to http://localhost:8080/other-application then I expect my endpoint to be there at http://localhost:8080/other-application/rest/acg-status but not http://localhost:8080/rest/acg-status

Comment: @OleksiyDeverishchev is your application boot strapped with a webapplicationinitializer ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this simply by using the spring boot Application Launcher class in your main project as below (You don't need WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class):

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.atomic.contentguard"})
public class AcgLauncher extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    //This method is required to launch the ACG application
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Launch Trainserv Application
        SpringApplication.run(AcgLauncher.class, args);
    }
}
```

Spring Boot uses this class during the server startup and scans the specified packages for all spring components (controllers, services, components).